# Perl Regex to parse first anchor <a> tag

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have below HTML page having two `anchor` tags as input to my perl script:

```
<a href="link.html"> TITLE </a> <a href="link.html"> SUB TITLE </a>
```

I want to extract only title i.e. I need text only from first anchor tag `<a>` and second anchor tag `<a>` text should be ignored. And this I need to do using Perl Regex only.

I've tried below Regex, but its not working as expected:

```
<a[^>]*[^>]*>(?!.*a>.*)a>
```

The whole script goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '<a href="link.html"> TITLE </a> <a href="link.html"> SUB TITLE </a>';

my $res = $str =~ m/<a[^>]*[^>]*>(?!.*a>.*)a>/;

print $res;
```

**Execution:**

```
 prakash@prak-pc:~$ perl regtest.pl 
 prakash@prak-pc:~$
```

Comment: Why not use a proper HTML parser like [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM), [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) or [HTML::LinkExtor](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::LinkExtor) ? Please also [edit] your post and show us some representative input data that shows how your code fails. Also tell us how your existing Regex fails to work as expected.

Comment: If you don't execute match globally,  `<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>` is enough. See it here https://regex101.com/r/SvqGvi/1

Comment: @Corion, There is the specified requirement that not to use any ready made modules.
Sure, I'll post the whole script.

Comment: If this is homework, please tell us so upfront. Otherwise, have your sysadmin install the ready made modules.

Comment: Not like homework its the requirement given by manager.

Comment: Then [edit] your post and tell us how your existing regex fails. We will need a [mcve] before we can proceed further. On the other hand, it's not hard to install one of these modules, or copy one of the modules into your source code.

Comment: @Corion, Edited. Please check now and help me.

Comment: `my $res = $str =~ /<a[^>]*[^>]*>(?!.*4a>.*)a>/;` should be `my ($res) = ($str =~ /<a[^>]*[^>]*>(?!.*a>.*)a>/);`

Comment: Why do you have duplicate `[^>]*[^>]*` just one is enough `[^>]*` and what is the negative lookahead for?

Comment: Have a try with: `(my $res) = $str =~ m~<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>~;`

Comment: @Toto, Yes this worked for me. Many thanks. Please this as Answer so that  many will be benefited. But its adding one white space before "TITLE" .

Comment: @PrakashG: Why is your manager forcing you to do this without modules? Sounds like you need a better manager (or a better job). Parsing HTML (or XML) using regexes is a terrible idea.

Comment: @DaveCross, Yes, indeed. I'm in search. If you find one plmk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $str = '<a href="link.html"> TITLE </a> <a href="link.html"> SUB TITLE </a>';
my ($res) = $str =~ m~<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>~;
print $res,"\n";
```

**Explanation:**

```
m~          # match operator, delimiter
    <a      # literally <a
    [^>]*   # 0 or more any character tat is not >
    >       # >
    (.*?)   # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
    </a>    # literally
~           # regex delimiter
```

You can use `m~<a[^>]*>\h*(.*?)\h*</a>~` if you don't want the leading and trailing spaces to be matched.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(?:<a[^>]*>)([^<]*)/
```

see the demo on regex101
    https://regex101.com/r/Po3goc/1

- ^ asserts position at start of a line Non-capturing group
  (?:]*>) ]*

  - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

    > matches the character > literally (case sensitive)
    >   matches the character > literally (case sensitive) 1st Capturing Group ([^<]*) Match a single character not present in the list below
    >   [^<]*
  - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) < matches the
    character < literally (case sensitive)